# Мгновенные сообщения

Tags: php, node.js, centos, vps

На чем лучше реализовывать это дело? Допустим, чтобы выдерживало 50 клиентов.

Также необходимо сохранение истории, во общем что-то очень близко похожее на *Диалоги* сами знаете где.

У меня есть [**VPS**](http://hosting.reg.ru/vps/plan/VPS-2-1011) на CentOS с PHP + MySQL, Apache, Nginx.

Comment: sockeet.io + google + brain = profit

Answer (score 1):

Так а.. я всегда думал, что самый лучший способ, это ajax.. чем он вас не устраивает? Тем более с выделенным сервером.http://javascript.ru/ajax - здесь всё, что может вам понадобиться.
даже у меня вышел неплохой чат, который я писал специально для того, чтобы разобраться с Ajax

Comment: Извиняюсь за нарушение пунктационных норм, с телефона не удобно набирать..

Comment: Эм. Вопрос про серверную часть. То что ajax это однозначно же, comet тоже понятно. Но PHP+MySQL+COMET это слишком ресурсоемко, и мой сервер умирает когда я нечайно делаю много запросов к нему.

Comment: Да, с таким я не работал, в пальцем в небо советовать не буду)

Comment: COMET не альтернатива Ajax'у, а его дополнение, разве я не прав?

Comment: Альтернативой его не назвать, грубо говоря это технология основанная на Ajax, которая повзоляет не делает "лишних телодвижений", а значит позволяет уменьшить нагрузку.

Comment: COMET это тот же самый AJAX только с другими настройками (timeout).

Comment: Значит Вы не знаете что такое COMET.

Comment: @GenchiK, [Да ладно?][1]


  [1]: http://spectrox.ru/blog/comet-theory-beginning/

Comment: Авторитетный источник :D Да... Я думал вы книги читаете, а вы блоги.

Comment: Повторите тормозу(мне то есть), сервер должен спокойно справлять со 150 mysql-запросами в секунду? или я опять ничего не понял?

Comment: Приходится удалять комменты чтобы вам ответить. А как вы думаете справляются сервера со 100 000 запросов? Или 500 000? 150 з / с - это капля в море.

Comment: @GenchiK, я не прочитал ни одной книги по веб-разработке. Зачем это когда есть интернет?

Comment: Вы путаете, для чего служит ajax, а для чего comet. Это главная ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вам поможет [`phpDaemon`](http://phpdaemon.net/).

Comment: Ответ вижу — почитаю, посмотрю.

Answer (score -2):

Меня иногда ответы убивают :D с утра настроение уже.

Способ такой (я не буду равняться на какой-то движок, но да - предпочел бы node.js): серверу приходит сообщение, сообщение записываем в массив. Т.е. у нас уже есть некая удобная структура - удобно как вынимать значения, так и управлять ими.

Если пользователь заходит в чат, то вываливаем ему все сообщения.

Рассмотрим теперь случай, если пришло сообщение. Значит так: какой-то пользователь отправил сообщение на сервер. Сервер его записал в массив. Дальше важный момент: скрипт смотрит, кто висит на ожидании сообщения от сервера со специальным флагом (который обозначает, что пользователь уже зашел в чат, получил список сообщений и ожидает новые сообщения) и отправляет этим ожидающим сообщение.

И хранить текст в памяти - ничего страшного по моему. Прикрутить сохранение сообщений через каждые n минут, и при завершении приложения.

Comment: Как сервер может сам что-то отправить, без запроса?

Comment: есть конечно WebSocket, но чёрт возьми, как его реализовать?!

Comment: @Dazar, это и есть COMET, он прослушивает события и реагирует не них, типо триггеров в MySQL.

Comment: Проблема в том, что сервер не может держать 50 соединений. 50 соединений каждую секунду делают проверку на новые сообщения + online пользователей + диалоги (вдруг кто новый написал). Это три запроса (с join) каждую секунду. Для PHP это ресурсозатратно, учитывая то, что весь сайт пока что будет работать на одном сервере.

Comment: Вы прежде чем говорить, прочтите что я написал, COMET НЕ ДЕЛАЕТ ПРОВЕРКИ, он реагирует на действия! И без хорошей базы знаний, не надо за такие вещи даже браться.

Comment: @exec, 150 запросов в секунду.. Бедненький сервер=)

Comment: @GenchiK, да какая еще база знаний, там всё элементарно. 


COMET это постоянное соединение которое обрывается и возвращает ответ когда на сервере есть изменения. Всё.

Comment: Так почему ещё не сделали? Тут не в сервере проблема для 50 соединений :D

Comment: @GenchiK, ваша ссылка хороша, однако там не учитывается, что Firefox и Opera отказались от WebSokets. Это не критично, но при изучении надо учитывать.

Comment: Я думал вы умеете читать внимательно, конец разговра. Firefox, Opera: Это временный отказ, стандарт должны утвердить к 2020 году. А пока это не стандарт, они могут себе позволить на время отказаться. Чтобы что-то умное написать, нужно знать детали.

Comment: Что вы за фигню тут написали? В данном варианте, который я предложил на node.js сервер и 100 соединений выдержит. Если не понимаете, как это работает, то пока рано браться за это. sql база тут нафиг не нужна. В вопросе вообще ничего про mysql не говорится. Все сообщения, повторю, хранятся в памяти.